# Try-catch on PostgreSQL not catching exception

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

i am testing postgreSQL connection using Npgsql . i want to know what happens when i make a mistake ,for example wrong connection string ,database is down .... etc. so i made this simple program to test Npgsqlexceptions but the try statement is not catching the exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Npgsql;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
     NpgsqlConnection conn = new         NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=knbvbnv;Database=testdb;");
         try
         {
            conn.Open();

         }
         catch (NpgsqlException ee)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("========  ee.Code  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Code);
            Console.WriteLine("========  ee.ColumnName  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.ColumnName);
            Console.WriteLine("========   ee.ConstraintName ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.ConstraintName);
            Console.WriteLine("========  ee.DataTypeName  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.DataTypeName);
            Console.WriteLine("======== Detail   ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Detail);
            Console.WriteLine("========  ErrorCode  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("========  HResult  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.HResult);
            Console.WriteLine("======== InternalQuery   ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.InternalQuery);
            Console.WriteLine("======== Message   ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("========  MessageText  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.MessageText);
            Console.WriteLine("========  Position  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Position);
            Console.WriteLine("========  Severity  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Severity);
            Console.WriteLine("======== TargetSite   ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.TargetSite);
            Console.WriteLine("========  Where  ===============");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.Where);
            Console.WriteLine("========    ===============");

         }
      }
   }
}
```

how come try does not catch errors ?

exception in visual studio is :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in Npgsql.dll

Additional information: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 3):

It's throwing a `SocketException`. You're catching a `NpgsqlException`. If you add a secondary catch for a `SocketException`, then it'll catch.

Comment: Thank you. i would love to know how did you come to figure out that SocketException is the exception thrown, as that will help me find my way in the future.

Comment: It's the exact error message you posted. "Unhandled exception of <type> was thrown." That's the type of exception it is, and if you don't catch that or something it inherits from (ie just a general `catch (Exception ex)` it'll still crash. I think you can also just do `catch` without specifying a particular type, but this is *usually* not a great idea. But I might be mixing that up with Java, I forget.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but for wrong connection string NOTSupportedException or IoException has been thrown which will catch with general exception class, for database down or not exist error get displayed "Database not exist" with NPGSqlException class.
Check with general exception class.